# Why does event.stopPropagation() stop multiple matched elements in delegated events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-delegation

When using delegated events, all matching elements trigger the event as it bubbles up from the target.

Based on https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ and refering to HTML and JS below, clicking on div-four triggers click events on all its ancestors (div-one, div-two, div-three, body) as it bubbles up. I am putting the event handler on body, selecting for `:not(#div-three)`

This can be seen in https://jsfiddle.net/bLw7ch50/1/ where clicking on div 4 for example, triggers 3 alerts. For div-four, div-two and div-one.

I think what happens is something like this:

1. Click on `div-four`, click event from `div-four` triggered.
2. `div-four` event bubble to `div-three`, click event from `div-three` triggered.
3. `div-four` event bubble to `div-two`, click event from `div-two` triggered.
4. `div-four` event bubble to `div-one`, click event from `div-one` triggered.
5. `div-four` event bubble to `body`, click event from `body` triggered. Event handler runs. Reporting `target:div-four|current:div-four`.
6. `div-three` (from step2) event bubbles up to `body`. Does not trigger event handler.
7. `div-two` (from step3) event bubbles to `body`. Event handler runs. Reporting `target:div-four|current:div-two`.
8. `div-one` (from step4) event bubbles to `body`. Event handler runs. Reporting `target:div-four|current:div-one`.

If a `event.stopPropagation()` is called in the event handler, the `div-four` event stops bubbling at step 5. (Although there's nothing to bubble above `body` anyway.) However, the events triggered in steps 2,3,4 should still exist and bubble up, thus steps 6,7,8 will still continue.

However, this does not appear to be the case. In the following https://jsfiddle.net/bLw7ch50/, after uncommenting  `event.stopPropagation()`, only 1 alert appears, `target:div-four|current:div-four`. So I'm probably wrong somewhere. What's wrong with my understanding?

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="div-one">
    1st div
    <div id="div-two">
      2nd div
      <div id="div-three">
        3rd div
        <div id="div-four">
          4th div
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="output">
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Javascript (with jquery1.9.1)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ":not(#div-three)", function(event) {
    var event_target = $(event.target).attr("id");
    var event_current = $(event.currentTarget).attr("id");
    $("#output").append("target:" + event_target +
                        "|current:" + event_current + "<br/>");
    alert("target:" + event_target +
          "|current:" + event_current);
    // Commented out in https://jsfiddle.net/bLw7ch50/1/, exists in https://jsfiddle.net/bLw7ch50
    event.stopPropagation(); // When this line is here, all other events stop
  });
});
```

Comment: because... for a delegated event to occur, the event must propagate up to the delegate target... if you stop propagation on any handler along the way, it won't propagate.

Comment: ..Umm there's no more propagation after propagating to `body`? Are you saying that the event propagates to `body` again?

Comment: it only propagates once to the document, then again back down. it doesn't start again at each element in between, there's only one event. if you stop it, it's stopped.

Comment: Wait, first of all, what do you mean by "it only propagates once to the document, then again back down"? Events go from _document to the target, then back up_ no? And, if there's only 1 event, why does it fire 3 times without `event.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: Yes, the opposite of what i said, :) it's firing three times because three elements that were eligible for the event were descendants of the delegate target (and in the event chain, or whatever you call it. elements between the original target and the delegate target.)

Comment: You are overcomplicating it, an event only bubbles once, not once per ancestor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening all within jQuery's event delegation, it has nothing to do with the way events bubble other than that jQuery is trying to mimic what happens with normal events.

With a normal event handler, if you `stopPropagation` that event will no longer bubble up the tree and ancestors with handlers on the same event type won't receive it. This is the same logic that is used to decide whether or not an event handler should be called for an element when using event delegation.

When you bind an event using delegation, you're only binding one event to the delegate target. When the event handler (not your event handler, jQuery's internal one) is triggered, jQuery looks through the elements that were between the original event target and the delegate target, then filters those based on the selector and calls the handler on them in order from the original event target to the delegate target. If any one of those handlers `stopPropagation`, no other elements within the list of eligible event targets will have the handler called. No additional events are triggered in this process.

This system also takes into account other delegated events.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.box1', function () {
    console.log('first box1 handler');
});

$(document).on('click', '.box1', function (e) {
    console.log('second box1 handler');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).on('click', '.box2', function () {
    console.log('first box2 handler');
});

$(document).on('click', '.box2', function (e) {
    console.log('second box2 handler');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">
<div class="box1">
<div class="box1">
<div class="box1">
click here to begin
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="box2">
<div class="box2">
<div class="box2">
<div class="box2">
click here to begin without propagation
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If you click the first box you'll only get first handler and second handler called once because we stopped propagating on the innermost div. Both still get called because we used `stopPropgation` and not `stopImmediatePropagation`. If you click the second, both handlers will get called once for each box div in the correct order.

---

Unfortunately I was unable to find any documentation to support this.